# How to read and write a map efficiently using mutex?

Tags: go

I'm reading a json file that has 1kk+ of objects and i need to organize **and count** some data and to do that I've created two maps so i can write and read into it, when I'm running a simple loop the code takes 40s to complete, example:

```
var acc int
firstContent := make(map[string]int)
secondContent := make(map[string]int)

decoder := json.NewDecoder(bufio.NewReader(file))

for decoder.More() {
    var dt &MyStruct{}
    decoder.Decode()

    if _, ok := firstContent[dt.Name]; !ok {
        firstContent["some-data"] = 1
        acc++ // count the uniqueness
    } else {
        firstContent["some-data"] += 1
    }

    if _, ok := secondContent[dt.City]; !ok {
        first["some-data"] = 1
    } else {
        first["some-data"] += 1
    }
}
```

I tried to optimize using `goroutines` and `mutex` to avoid concurrency, but when I use it, it takes longer to finish.

```
var mutex = sync.RWMutex{}

for reader.More() {
    var dt &MyStruct{}
    reader.Decode(&dt)

    go func(name string) {
        mutex.Lock()
        if _, ok := firstContent[name]; !ok {
            firstContent[name] = 1 // need to convert to *int64, i know...
            atomic.AddInt32(acc, 1)
        } else {
            atomic.AddInt64(firstContent[name], 1)
        }
        mutex.Unlock()
    }(dt.Name)

    go func(city string) {
        mutex.Lock()
        if _, ok := secondContent[city]; !ok {
            secondContent[city] = 1
        } else {
            atomic.AddInt(secondContent[city], 1)
        }
        mutex.Unlock()
    }(dt.City)
}
```

Why is it taking longer to finish? Because of `mutex.Lock()`? how can i improve the speed in this case?

Comment: By 1kk+ do you mean more than 1 000 000?

Comment: The parts you put into the goroutines are trivial. The cost of creating goroutines, locking far exceeds the cost of doing the actual job. Run a profiler and see if there is a bottleneck in the program. It is more likely that the size of the input requires that much processing.

Comment: yes @AndrewMorton, 1 million or more

Answer (score 0):

Your issue cannot be fixed by concurency. Thing that takes most of the time is parsing of a json, and not counting the names. You can say that this situation is little bit of paradox as you have to read file on single thread. Maybe spliting file into smaller files and processing each on separate thread can help, if you can do that of course.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jakub above said, you could split the input file and process on separate goroutines (like a MapReduce framework) which would definitely speed it up.

Also, have you tried creating a go-struct of the objects in the JSON file and marshalling it into a list of them and doing the computations from there? Not sure if that would be better but its an idea.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how would i split the file in chunks?

Comment: I think if you just have a file with a JSON list of objects you should unmarshall those into a list of their structs, then you could do it all on one goroutine (main thread) or shard that list and call a separate goroutine that does the logic you want and feeds results to a channel + a waitgroup for all to finish.